# How large is an airship? (Dimensions) How much room does one have below decks?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, equipment

My players are getting an airship and I was wondering if they would be able to mod it in various ways, like adding a brig or expanding the storage. I was wondering how much room they would have to build onto it.

Comment: Did you consider using the illustration of a boat/ship in the DMG for your deck plan and just adding the lift producing part?

Comment: Voting to re-open, as this can now be answered by citing the size range and cargo capacity of atmosphere-capable spelljamming craft as well as information about modifying deck plans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only information available to us in D&D 5E about Airships comes from the DMG and an entry in

> Storm King's Thunder.

They are mentioned as existing in other adventure modules, but the only thing like stats comes from a single line on DMG 119, and

> SKT 133-135.

The DMG gives you the functional stats of the airship, but nothing in the way of dimensions. The only sort-of useful information it provides here is the crew compliment, the max number of passengers, and how much cargo it can carry. 10 Crewmen, 20 Passengers, 1 ton of cargo. The exact dimensions are unknown...because we don't know how much space is dedicated to each crewman, how much space is dedicated to each passenger, how much space is dedicated to the operation of the ship, and so on.

> SKT features a much smaller airship (Crew of 2, ~6 passengers). It also includes a map that could be a good reference for you, and descriptions of how the ship works.

From this point on...you're in purely homebrew territory. I can point you in a direction that would potentially be helpful...but I cannot offer you a concrete answer, because no such answer exists.

So, you have two options here, as far as I can say.

Simple: You know the ship can carry 20 passengers...so allow your players to 'secure' some of the passenger cabins to serve as a brig. This is the simplest way to do it, and can be handled by having them shell out some money to reinforce the walls, and replace the door with a sturdy one that locks. Alternately, they could sacrifice their cargo capacity to put manacles down in the cargo hold and use that as a brig. This is the easy way that doesn't require a lot of work on your part.

Detailed: The best reference I can aim you at for truly homebrewing up an airship is the 3.5E Conversion of the Spelljammer ship creation rules. Obviously, this isn't going to be perfect, because a Spelljammer flies according to very different rules than a normal airship. But...the rules for determining how large it is, how much stuff you can put inside of it, etc...those are very helpful.

An important thing to bear in mind...in this document 'Tonnage' is NOT representative of a physical ton of weight or of a ton of cargo. It is a ship-scale reference for size that represents a cube measuring 1,350 cubic feet. Assuming a 9-foot ceiling, that means 1 'Ton' of ship is 30 5x5 squares. Again, this is NOT a perfect answer, but it is the only pre-made homebrew tool I have found that fills out that level of detail aboard a ship, if you so desire.

The pdf for these rules can be found here: http://lost.spelljammer.org/TBLIV/lsccs3e/3eShipConstruction.pdf

Thanks to suggestion from nitsua60. I would like to point out that while converting 3.5 content to 5e is generally something of a nightmare, I have found this particular conversion to be quite simple. That fan-made Ship Construction guide is better organized than the original AD&D Spelljammer construction guide, and is simple and straight forward to work with.

Comment: Thanks! I was a little disappointed that the PH or DMG didn't have this, even though they have basically anything else...

Comment: @nitsua60 You are correct, I missed the map of the airship in Storm King's Thunder, I'll amend my answer to include that. In answer to why I'd suggest using the 3.5 guide....it is simply better organized that the original Shipyard content in old Spelljammer. And, functionally, it's practically identical in terms of the actual building and designing of what goes into a ship (as it is, itself, a port of the 2E rules).

Comment: You might wrap the SKT airship section in spoiler tags... I'll be playing this adventure soon and found it to be a bit of a spoiler.  :(

Answer (score 2):

I also have been planning on giving my PCs an airship soon in our campaign so I have been thinking about this a lot.  Airships can be as big as the system that keeps them afloat.  If you are using the kind that have a balloon, then the ship has to be a bit smaller or have more/larger balloons.  If you are doing it with some sort of magic or an Elemental Ring that goes around the ship's midsection, you have more liberties on the size.

As for the actual dimensions of an airship, here is an example that I found online.  It doesn't say what scale the squares are (5' or 10'), so it is either 15 feet wide or 30, and 60 or 120 feet long respectively.  Note still that there doesn't appear to be that much room for something like the brig you suggested they might add.  With something like that, you may want to encourage them to be creative as to where they put it, such as gibbet cages hanging from a cross beam specifically added to the mast for that purpose.  Also, from what I know of regular seaworthy ships, if you want to expand the storage, you are either going to lose space for something else, or you're going to need a bigger ship.  You can't just make a ship longer or wider; you start with it being larger or wider.

[image: Airship Image Example]

Now if it were me, I would give my players the larger size, so it feels like they have more room.  Of course, some of my players run multiple characters, so we have a max party size of 8, plus a summoned tiger and a few horses.

**Conclusion**
Honestly, as DM you have free rein over what you say the size is and what you allow them to do to the ship.  I am positive my party are going to want to upgrade the ship (of course it's going to be a bit beaten up to begin with) so I will entertain them and their ideas until it gets too unrealistic.  You set the bounds to what they can and can't do.  If they want a bigger ship, then they are going to be a bigger target.  If they want speed, they will likely have a smaller ship and be able to carry less.

So, give them what you think won't break the campaign, have fun, and watch their eyes light up when you describe them seeing it for the first time!